# При создании "New Data Source" в ColdFusion возникает "Could not create connection to database"

Tags: mysql

Я пишу обычное CRUD приложение с использованием ColdFusion. Пытаюсь подключиться к MySQL из-под ColdFusion: в панели администратора `ColdFusion` [localhost:8600/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm](http://localhost:8600/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm) зашёл в `DataSources`, чтобы добавить `New Data Source`, в качестве драйвера выбрал `MySQL 5`, получил сообщение:

> Connection verification failed for data source: dsnYumasoft
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver available for dsnYumasoft, please check the driver setting in resources file, error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

[image: что нет драйвера] 
Пошёл за ним на [dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), но там всё для линукса, а у меня винда, выставил `Platform Independent` скачал zip-архив, оттуда извлёк .jar-ник и поместил его в `cf_root\ColdFusion\cfusion\lib` (но я не уверен, что нужно сюда, так как в вышеупомянутой админ-панели написано, что кидать нужно в `cf_root/lib`, а именно такой папки у меня нет, и дополнительно я закинул ещё сюда `cf_root\ColdFusion\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\lib`). Далее столкнулся с такой ошибкой:

> Connection verification failed for data source: dsnYumasoft
>   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

[image: Не получается присоединиться к БД]
Порт 3306 открыт, проверял через telnet.
В админ-панели ColdFusion пробовал в `Server` писать и `localhost` и `127.0.0.1`; а в `Database` пробовал писать и имя схемы и имя сокета.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Отключал firewall, – и пока ещё не смог побороть, кто может направить меня в нужное русло?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в **версии** [mysql connector java](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).
Сначала я использовал последнюю версию `Connector/J 8.0.11` а нужно использовать предыдущую `Connector/J 5.1.46`.
[image]